# Obstruction for a compact simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-complex, obstruction-theory

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $X$ be a compact simplicial complex and $Y$ be based, connected space with $f:X\to Y.$ If $X$ is simply connected and $f_k:=f\mid_{X^k}$. Show that $f_1$ is nullhomotopic where $X^k$ is the $k-$th sub complex of $X.$

Also show that if a specific nullhomotopy has been selected for $f_k$ then there is an obstruction to extending it to a nullhomotopy for $f_{k+1}$ and show that it is a combinatorial cochain $z$ of dimension $k+1$ on $X$ with coefficients in $π_{k+1}(Y,*).$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ As, $S^1$ is a finite simplicial complex then any map from $S^1$ to $X$ is homotopic to a simplicial map $s$ (by Simplicial Approximation theorem) and $s$ is nullhomotopic.
Now, again $Y$ has a CW and hence a simplicial approximation $Y^s$ but then $f$ becomes homotopic to a simplicial map .

I can't approach any further .
Geometrically,  I can think that $X^1$ is convex combination of some subset of $X^0$ and the $1-$simplices in $X^1$ can be contracted to a point, but I am very sloppy here .

Do I need to invoke geometric realization of $X$ here ?

And I am clueless about 2nd problem . Can anyone suggest a good reference for Obstruction theory for finite simplicial complexes?

Thanks in advance for any help .

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is simply connected, $X^1$ is connected. Being a graph, it must be equivalent to a wedge of circles (collapse a maximal tree). But then each circle maps to a loop in $X$ which must be homotopically trivial, so performing these homotopies simultaneously we get that $X^1 \to X$ is nullhomotopic. But $f_1$ by assumption is the composition $X^1 \to X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ so must also be nullhomotopic.